# How To Convert a BIN file to ISO on Linux 14.04 Using PowerIso?

Tags: iso, convert

I need to know how to convert a BIN file to an ISO file. I've tried using `bchunk`. And for some reason, it didn't work.

Now I have `PowerIso` and I want to convert my `Final Fantasy VIII (Disc 1).bin` file to an iso file so `PCSX` will run it. Can someone tell me how to do this? Thanks.

*Edit:*

According to PowerIso, this is the example they use for converting an image file to another format, followed by the command.

```
 convert <image file>    Convert image file to other format.
     Example:  Convert /home/sam/test.daa to standard iso file 
     Command:  poweriso convert /home/sam/test.daa -o /home/sam/test.iso -ot iso
```

I put:

```
poweriso convert /home/sam/Final Fantasy VIII Disc 1.cue -o /home/sam/Final Fantasy VIII Disc 1.iso -ot iso
```

All I get when I put this in is:

> Unrecognized parameter: Fantasy

Comment: A .bin file that provides a disk image usually has an accompanying .cue file. Do you have that? To work, it should be in the same folder as the .bin file and have the same name except for the .bin and .cue suffixes. Most utilities that mount or convert cue/bin images, at least that I've seen or used, prefer to operate on the .cue rather than the .bin as the .cue is what contains track data (i.e., information about where the one or more tracks on the imaged disc start and end). Some will only take the .cue as an argument. I also recommend you [edit] this with the specific commands you're using.

Comment: I do have the .cue file as well.

Comment: I suggest that you rename Final Fantasy VIII Disc 1.cue to Final-Fantasy-VIII-Disc-1.cue. And you try again.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> poweriso convert /home/sam/Final Fantasy VIII Disc 1.cue -o /home/sam/Final Fantasy VIII Disc 1.iso -ot iso
> ```
>
> All I get when I put this in is: `Unrecognized parameter: Fantasy`

This is a typical error message: you need to tell the program that the spaces and other possibly contained special characters are not the beginning of a new parameter but the same path statement.

This should work:

```
poweriso convert "/home/sam/Final Fantasy VIII Disc 1.cue" -o "/home/sam/Final Fantasy VIII Disc 1.iso" -ot iso
```

Comment: You can also put a back slash "\" before every space. `poweriso convert /home/sam/Final\ Fantasy\ VIII\ Disc\ 1.cue -o /home/sam/Final\ Fantasy\ VIII\ Disc\ 1.iso -ot iso`

Comment: @Cammy_the_block Of course, but that would be much more error prone and deserve a better explanation.

Comment: I was just including for completeness. Besides user error is it any more error prone?